# Mysql - select multiple inserted records

Tags: mysql, insert

How to select multiple inserted records in same stored procedure?

```
INSERT INTO cars (type, status_id) 
VALUES ('GM',1),
       ('Toyota',2),
       ('Honda',3);
```

cars has an AUTO_INCREMENT PK field called car_id.
let's say the table was inserted

1556 GM 1

1557 Toyota 2

1558 Honda 3

How can I select it?

Comment: I thought maybe to get ROW_COUNT() and then select last ROW_COUNT() records. will that work?

Comment: first of all what you want....you want insert or count...

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL inserting multiple records with a select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215788/mysql-inserting-multiple-records-with-a-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the results of these two functions:

- [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)
- [`ROW_COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count)

like this:

```
INSERT INTO cars (type, status_id) 
VALUES ('GM',1),
       ('Toyota',2),
       ('Honda',3);

SELECT *
FROM cars
WHERE car_id BETWEEN LAST_INSERT_ID()
                 AND LAST_INSERT_ID() + ROW_COUNT() - 1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, was pretty easy to solve.

```
declare new_cars int;
INSERT INTO cars (name, type) 
VALUES  ('GM',1),
        ('Toyota',2),
        ('Honda',3);
select row_count() into new_cars;
select * from cars
order by car_id desc
limit new_cars;
```

Comment: Is there any better way?